# I think immutable types like frozenset and tuple not actually copied. What is this called? Does it have any implications?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was messing around while trying to figure out shallow and deep copying in Python, and noticed that while the identities of a copied set, list, or seemingly any mutable type aren't the same:

```
In[2]: x1 = {1,2,3}
In[3]: x2 = x1.copy()
In[4]: x1 is x2
Out[4]: False
```

For immutable types this isn't the case - it looks like a copy points to the same address in memory.

```
In[6]: f1 = frozenset({1,2,3})
In[7]: f2 = f1.copy()
In[8]: f1 is f2
Out[8]: True
```

This sort of intuitively makes sense to me - why would you need two identical immutable objects in memory anyways. But I've never seen it before - is there a name for this process? Is it done for speed purposes?

Furthermore, are there any implications of this "not actual copying"? I'm not convinced there are but I want to be sure - the only thing I could come up with is if someone decided to modify mutable types inside an immutable type, which from what I know would be a bad idea anyways.

```
In[11]: t1 = tuple((1, ['a', 'b']))
In[12]: t2 = tuple(t1) # I would expect an actual copy, but it is not
In[13]: t1[1].append('c')
In[14]: t2
Out[14]: (1, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: There's no special name for *"not copying"*, funnily enough.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Apologies if it is a silly question  - for some reason I thought I must be missing it documented somewhere with a name and an explanation. Especially because the `help` built-in on frozenset for instance say that `copy` returns a shallow copy, and I thought that meant you had to construct a new compound object.

Comment: Keep in mind that in Python a variable is like a *label* used to reference an object. You can hang many labels on the same object.

For immutable objects it doesn't make sense to actually copy them (and it saves memory if you don't copy them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [*polymorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

Different types can implement the `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()` hooks and do something different that makes sense to their type. The [`copy` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) simply calls those hooks to delegate the actual copy work (or in the case of the set types, you delegate to the `set.copy()` method). Immutable types then are free to return `self` to avoid wasting memory.

Otherwise, there is no special name for the choice to return `self` from `__copy__()` for immutable types.

Note that for the tuple-with-list example, you only asked for a *shallow copy*. Shallow copies of containers always re-use the references to the contents. The same thing would happen with `list(some_list_object)` or `dict(some_dict_object)`. Use a *deep copy* instead to ensure that you get a tuple with a copy of the contained list; a new tuple object is then created too:

```
>>> import copy
>>> t1 = (1, ['a', 'b'])
>>> t2 = copy.deepcopy(t1)
>>> t1 is t2
False
>>> t1[0].append('c')
>>> t2
(1, ['a', 'b'])
```

Comment: I may be mistaken but isn't this called interning (from CPython)?

Comment: No, interning is reusing objects based on value. So returning an already created integer when you use the literal `1`.

Comment: Right - I was confused with recalling reading about interning for small integers in CPython, thanks.